# Removing "<a0>" values from my data frame

Tags: dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC9r0.jpg)I have a data frame of industries divided into six sectors. I brought the excel file (xlsx format) into R by the gdata package. Now what I observe is that infront of some of the name of the firms and also against some dummy variables, the letter  appears and this was not in my original excel sheet. and this is random - some names are followed by this and some don't. Can somebody tell me how do I get rid of these  signs?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] - in this case a line creating a small dataframe that produces an example table containing such cells would be enough.

Comment: Hi I have added an image from the data editor. If you look at row 2, column 5 and also row 5, column 1 (just to give two examples), you would observe <a0> after the values/words. This was not there in my original excel sheet

Comment: install.packages("gdata")
library(gdata)
dataframe <- read.xls("FileName", sheet="Sheet1", header = TRUE)
This is the code that I had used to import data from my excel sheet.